# Why not imaginary eigenvalues in the eigenvalue equation $A\psi=\lambda\psi$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, eigenvalue

in quantum mechanics we always see the eigenvalue equation $\hat A\psi=\lambda\psi$ and $\lambda$ is the probability amplitude meaning $\lambda^2$ is the actual probability of finding the system in the state $\psi$. We are also told that $\lambda$ must be real, but what would be wrong with having $\lambda$ imaginary because it's square is real as a physical quantity must be?

So why can we never have a complex $\lambda$?

Comment: Lambda has nothing to do with the probability. Lambda is a possible measurement outcome upon measuring A. Why do you think it’s a probability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\lambda$ is *not* the probability amplitude. And your equation $\hat A\psi=\lambda\psi$ means that $\psi$ is an eigenstate of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is a *physical quantity* associated with $\hat A$ upon measurement of $\hat A$. Hence $\lambda$ itself must be *real*.

For example, if $\hat A$ was the momentum operator, then $\lambda$ is a value of momentum. And in the ubiquitous equation, $$\hat H\Psi=E\Psi$$ where $\hat H$ is the Hamiltonian, $E$ is energy.

You have a few misconceptions. Say we have a system described by a state
$$\Psi=\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\psi_1  +\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\psi_2$$ Then the coefficients $\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}$ and $\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$ are probability *amplitudes* and the corresponding
square of these coefficients i.e., $\frac 13$ and $\frac 23$ are *probabilities* (corresponding to the
likelihood of finding the system in states $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ respectively).

When you look at the equation $\hat A\psi=\lambda\psi$ (with Hermitian or *self-adjoint* $\hat A$) by definition we need a coefficient $\lambda$ that will change the *length* of the
state $\psi$ and *not* a complex $\lambda$ since
multiplication by imaginary numbers will *rotate* a state.

Also, if the eigenvalues were imaginary, this would mean the operator $\hat A$ will *not* be Hermitian. This is because $\hat A$ will have imaginary elements on the diagonal. This means it *cannot* possibly be
Hermitian since the rule $$A^\dagger=(A^T)^*=A$$ cannot possibly hold.

Remember that the rule is that $\hat A$ must be Hermitian since it is also a requirement that $\hat A$ has a *complete* set of eigenvalues.

Comment: Where is "probability amplitude" referred to then?

Comment: I will edit my answer soon to elaborate.

Comment: ok i understand it. thanks.

Comment: No worries. Good luck with your studies. Cheers.